# Copy a .flif file partially

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, copy

I have a compressed .flif image. How do I copy it partially, so that I am able to simulate a partially received file over a low bandwidth connection?

Answer (score 2):

On *nix systems, you can just use the `dd` command. For example to copy only the first 1000 bytes from `in.flif` to `out.flif`:

```
dd bs=1 count=1000 in=in.flif out=out.flif
```

To determine the optimum points for truncation, use the the `-b` option to the `flif` CLI tool. It shows the breakpoints where a complete zoom level can be decoded.

```
> flif -b clock.flif
Image data starts at offset 12
1:8 scale: 5091 bytes
1:4 scale: 6654 bytes
1:2 scale: 10860 bytes
```

In the above example, truncating clock.flif at 5091 bytes will be optimal for 1:8 scale. That is, the luma values for every 8th pixel will be guaranteed to be available.

Answer (score 1):

#### Method 1. Cut the file at the exact position

You can use viewflif to know the offset where you can safely cut off the file. Using viewflif on flif image then

```
> viewflif chess.flif
Decoding progressively...
13057 bytes read, rendering at quality=5.46%
33940 bytes read, rendering at quality=19.27%
57488 bytes read, rendering at quality=38.54%
58958 bytes read, rendering at quality=52.08%
60574 bytes read, rendering at quality=68.75%
61231 bytes read, rendering at quality=83.33%
61942 bytes read, rendering at quality=100.00%
Closed
```

Numbers followed by `bytes read` are the offset I mentioned above. You can split the file with hex editor. But I don't know that's all of the point which we can split.

In fact, viewflif should show all of partially rendered image, but at least currently it doesn't work well on windows. (I had to adjust the window size to work well, it has no notion of the navigation, and its initial window size and interpolation method isn't satisfactory.)

#### Method 2. Adapt the poly-flif demo

Maybe you've already seen [this](https://uprootlabs.github.io/poly-flif/), and it may have been interesting enough. Then your primary objective is maybe comparison with other format on custom image.

Download entire page with the browser's 'save entire page' feature. Then you can see `imgInfo.js` in some resource folder. (If not, try with another browser.) You may change that and flif-demo's path constant adequately.

Then run your local static file server to downloaded html. But... it's just my guess on your intent. If you want to test web loading, then this will be appropriate (with devtool's bandwidth configuration and your own work, but it seems to be not easy).

Comment: PolyFLIF now has a well-defined API too. See documentation [here](https://uprootlabs.github.io/poly-flif/api.html). If the server supports range headers, then truncation can be automatically done on the fly. See the partial load and decode section.